# when transpiling mocha test using ts-node i cannot find module 'tsconfig/register'

Tags: node.js, typescript, mocha.js

I have run both `npm i ts-node` and `npm i ts-node --save-dev` with no changes. ts-node works fine when I run it from the command line, but for some reason I cannot run mocha tests through test explorer. I get the error below:

error:

```
{ Error: Cannot find module 'tsconfig/register'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at exports.requireOrImport (c:\Users\king\.vscode\extensions\hbenl.vscode-mocha-test-adapter-2.8.1\node_modules\mocha\lib\esm-utils.js:20:12)
    at c:\Users\king\.vscode\extensions\hbenl.vscode-mocha-test-adapter-2.8.1\out\worker\bundle.js:5663:41
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (c:\Users\king\.vscode\extensions\hbenl.vscode-mocha-test-adapter-2.8.1\out\worker\bundle.js:90:58) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "appts",
  "version": "1.1.1",
  "description": "",
  "main": "handler.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build:launchlocal": "cd serverless-site/ && npm start"
  },
  "mocha": {
  "require": ["tsconfig/register"]
},
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/aws-lambda": "^8.10.40",
    "@types/expect": "^24.3.0",
    "@types/mocha": "^8.0.3",
    "@types/validator": "^13.1.0",
    "serverless-offline": "^5.12.1",
    "serverless-plugin-typescript": "^1.1.9",
    "serverless-s3-sync": "^1.10.4",
    "serverless-step-functions": "^2.17.1",
    "ts-mocha": "^7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "^8.10.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    .....omitted....
  }
}
```

Comment: ok, looks like completely removing the mocah section from package.json and putting in a .mocharc file fixed this issue.... not sure why tests arent showing up however

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out none of the package.json config options were working for me. I wound up implementing a .mocharc.json on the same level as my package.json which worked perfectly.

Example from [this github repo (with more examples)](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha-examples/blob/master/packages/typescript/.mocharc.json) copied here for posterity.

```
{
  "extension": ["ts"],
  "spec": "src/**/*.spec.ts",
  "require": "ts-node/register"
}
```

Comment: Several years later- If you still have issues, try running the `mocha` command from the terminal. It may display an error in your test environment that the GUI output did not (eg a missing require statement)